# Google Testing a boost::variant

Tags: c++, boost, googletest, c++98

I have a boost::variant which contains commands. I'm writing a `PathValidator` visitor which behaves one way for the `Create` command and one way for all other commands. Here is how I'm testing. I will need to write more HelperVisitors as I add more tests. Any tips on how I can make this more readable and less verbose? I'm using C++98. Or maybe you think this is OK.

```
struct TestOneNodeInTreeHelper
{
    explicit TestOneNodeInTreeHelper(TestPathValidator& test): _test(test)
    {
    }

    void operator()(Create&) const
    {
        SyntaxTree::Create create;
        _test.addNodeToSyntaxTree(create.nodes,"1");
        PathValidator pathValidator(_test._accessorMock);
        pathValidator(create);
        EXPECT_EQ((int)_test._accessorMock->path.size(), 0);
    }

    template<class T> void operator()(const T&) const 
    {
        SyntaxTree::Create create;
        _test.addNodeToSyntaxTree(create.nodes,"1");
        PathValidator pathValidator(_test._accessorMock);
        pathValidator(create);
        EXPECT_EQ((int)_test._accessorMock->path.size(), 0);
        EXPECT_EQ(_test._accessorMock->path[0], "path1");
    }
    TestPathValidator& _test;
};

TEST_F (TestPathValidator, oneNodeInTree)
{
    TestOneNodeInTreeHelper helper(*this);
    boost::mpl::for_each<Command::types>(helper);
}
```